# How to retrieve data inside ASPxGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I am using ASPxGridView and inside grid view (`EditItemTemplate`) i have drop down list which is binding from web services and i want to insert selected drop down items in SQL database to retrieve data from drop down list I am using `FindControl` but no success.

I am using **Hierarchical grid view**  having three level

And Able to bind all drop down list But not able to save selected Drop down Items in data base,

ASPX

```xml
    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgDepots" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="grid"
        Width="100%"
        OnRowDeleting="dgDepots_RowDeleting" OnRowInserting="dgDepots_RowInserting" OnRowUpdating="dgDepots_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>
            <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="LocationCode" VisibleIndex="0">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <%--<select id="ddlLocation" name="ddlLocation" class="width50p input-tb"></select>--%>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="Select"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="CostCenterCode" VisibleIndex="1">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <%--<select id="ddlCostCenterCode" name="ddlCostCenterCode" class="width50p input-tb"></select>--%>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCostCenterCode" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="GLCode" VisibleIndex="2">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <%-- <select id="ddlGLCode" name="ddlGLCode" class="width50p input-tb"></select>--%>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGLCode" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
            <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowNewButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" VisibleIndex="2">
            </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
        </Columns>
        <Styles Header-BackColor="LightBlue" Header-Font-Bold="true">
            <Header BackColor="LightBlue" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium">
            </Header>
        </Styles>
        <Templates>
            <DetailRow>
                <dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgCustomers" runat="server"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="dsCustomers"
                    KeyFieldName="CustomerCode" OnBeforePerformDataSelect="dgCustomers_BeforePerformDataSelect"
                    Width="100%"
                    OnRowDeleting="dgCustomers_RowDeleting" OnRowInserting="dgCustomers_RowInserting"
                    OnRowUpdating="dgCustomers_RowUpdating">
                    <Columns>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="CustomerCode" VisibleIndex="1">
                        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="CustomerDesc" VisibleIndex="2">
                        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="PriceGroupCode" VisibleIndex="4">
                        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="ChannelCode" VisibleIndex="5">
                        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="SubChannelCode" VisibleIndex="5">
                        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowNewButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" VisibleIndex="6">
                        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                    </Columns>
                    <Styles Header-BackColor="LightBlue" Header-Font-Bold="true">
                        <Header BackColor="LightBlue" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium">
                        </Header>
                    </Styles>
                    <Templates>
                        <DetailRow>
                            <dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgProducts" runat="server"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="dsProducts"
                                KeyFieldName="ProductId"
                                OnBeforePerformDataSelect="dgProducts_BeforePerformDataSelect" Width="100%"
                                OnRowDeleting="dgProducts_RowDeleting" OnRowInserting="dgProducts_RowInserting"
                                OnRowUpdating="dgProducts_RowUpdating">
                                <Columns>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="ProductId" ReadOnly="False"
                                        VisibleIndex="0">
                                        <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                                    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="ProductCode" VisibleIndex="1">
                                    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="ProductDesc" VisibleIndex="2">
                                    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="CustomerId" VisibleIndex="3">
                                    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="CrateCaseConfig" VisibleIndex="4">
                                    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="PerDayQty" VisibleIndex="5">
                                    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="PromotQty" VisibleIndex="6">
                                    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowNewButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" VisibleIndex="7">
                                    </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                                </Columns>
                                <Styles Header-BackColor="LightBlue" Header-Font-Bold="true">
                                    <Header BackColor="LightBlue" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium">
                                    </Header>
                                </Styles>
                                <Templates>

                                    <DetailRow>

                                        <dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgPerDayQty" runat="server"
                                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="dsPerDayQty"
                                            KeyFieldName="Id"
                                            OnBeforePerformDataSelect="dgPerDayQty_BeforePerformDataSelect" Width="100%"
                                            OnRowDeleting="dgPerDayQty_RowDeleting" OnRowInserting="dgPerDayQty_RowInserting"
                                            OnRowUpdating="dgPerDayQty_RowUpdating">

                                            <Columns>

                                                <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Id" ReadOnly="False"
                                                    VisibleIndex="0">
                                                    <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                                                </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                                                <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="CollectionDate" VisibleIndex="1">
                                                </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                                                <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="PerDayQty" VisibleIndex="2">
                                                </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                                                <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="ProductId" VisibleIndex="3">
                                                </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                                                <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowNewButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" VisibleIndex="4">
                                                </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                                            </Columns>
                                            <Styles Header-BackColor="LightBlue" Header-Font-Bold="true">
                                                <Header BackColor="LightBlue" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium">
                                                </Header>
                                            </Styles>
                                            <%--<SettingsDetail IsDetailGrid="True" ShowDetailRow="True" />--%>
                                        </dx:ASPxGridView>
                                    </DetailRow>
                                </Templates>

                                <SettingsDetail ShowDetailRow="True" />
                            </dx:ASPxGridView>
                        </DetailRow>
                    </Templates>

                    <SettingsDetail IsDetailGrid="True" ShowDetailRow="True" />
                </dx:ASPxGridView>
            </DetailRow>
        </Templates>
        <SettingsDetail ShowDetailRow="true" />
        <Settings ShowGroupPanel="True" />
        <SettingsCustomizationDialog Enabled="True" />
    </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

.CS

```cs
protected void dgDepots_RowInserting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInsertingEventArgs e)
{               
    e.Cancel = false; 
    DropDownList list = (DropDownList)dgDepots.FindEditRowCellTemplateControl((GridViewDataColumn)dgDepots.Columns["LocationCode"], "ddlLocation") as DropDownList;
                
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Insert_Line_Item", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationCode", list.SelectedItem.Value); // NULL appearing 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationName", Location.SelectedItem.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GLCode", GLCode.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CostCenterCode", CostCeneterCode.SelectedValue);
    con.Open();
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}

  protected void dgCustomers_BeforePerformDataSelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["LocationCode"] = (sender as ASPxGridView).GetMasterRowKeyValue();
        }
protected void dgProducts_BeforePerformDataSelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["CustomerId"] = (sender as ASPxGridView).GetMasterRowKeyValue();
        }

        protected void dgPerDayQty_BeforePerformDataSelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["ProductId"] = (sender as ASPxGridView).GetMasterRowKeyValue();
        }
```

While debugging i can see its appearing `null`

where i am doing wrong? Please guide me.

[Please click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz48o.png)

Comment: Is `list` null in this case or `list.SelectedItem` or `list.SelectedItem.Value`? Depending on this there may be different causes and solutions.

Comment: @Leander  list.SelectedItem.Value is null

Comment: how about `list.SelectedIndex`? If that has a value you could use `list.Items[list.SelectedIndex]` to obtain the selected item.

Comment: @Leander list.SelectedItem is also null and I believe list will always null bcz list is initialing so first time it should be null please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Leander list.SelectedIndex  is  showing  -1

Comment: Index -1 means no item is selected. I'm getting a bit confused now in what you want to achieve... If I am correct when a new row is being added to the `GridView` you subsequently want to add it to the database? If you just want to obtain the `LocationCode` value of this new row, you could use `e.NewValues["LocationCode"]`.

Comment: when i add   <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="Select"></asp:ListItem> In drop down list now list.SelectedIndex is appearing 0

Comment: Which should mean that `list.SelectedItem.Value` should be equal to `"Select"`.

Comment: @Leander I want if i clicked new button I want to insert selected drop down value you can check my Updated question i have added screen shots of UI

Comment: Then you should be referencing to that combobox instead of the `DropDownList` from the `GridView` in the same way as how you are obtaining the `GL Code` and `CostCenterCode`...

Comment: @Leander Still i am not able to get GL Code and CostCenterCode. I am using dropdown list for all fields

Comment: Then there is more going on than just in the code you provided. You should show the code of your entire page or at least all relevant parts in their. E.g. the controls which you use to add a new item to the `GridView`.

Comment: Ok Please check my Updated Code